# Using jQuery, scroll a div's content's with the browser scrollbar without scrolling the page...

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I have a header area that is 575px high. I'd like the contents of this header div to scroll when the user moves the scrollbar or uses the mousewheel, but when the scrollbar reaches the end of that content, I need the entire window to start scrolling like normal.

Really Basic Sample Code:

```
<div id="header">

    <div id="text1">ONE</div>
    <div id="text2">TWO</div>
    <div id="text3">THREE</div>
    <div id="text4">FOUR</div>

</div>

<div id="main-content"></div>
```

I have JSfiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/3uefZ/5/

There are scrollbars on the header div - which I do not want :( but it's the only way  could get close to visualizing what I mean.

I'd love any help on this...

Thanks!

Comment: Besides the scrollbars being visible, doesn't this work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

http://jsfiddle.net/BbGdM/

```
var i = document.body.scrollTop;
var scrolling = true;
window.onscroll = function(){
    if(scrolling) {
        var old = document.getElementById("header").scrollTop
        document.getElementById("header").scrollTop += document.body.scrollTop;
        if( document.getElementById("header").scrollTop == old &&
            document.body.scrollTop > 0) {
            scrolling = false;
        }
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    }
}
```

rather hackish though... I so hope this is not a new breed of ads......

Comment: Nope - not an ad. I'm trying to get this parallax type effect that the designers want on the header content. Problem is that when I use the parallax plugins, I can get it to constrain to just the div area I want the effect on without hiding the overflow so the header content doesn't push the main content down in the layout. Overflow:hidden; renders the effect useless. I thought I'd try another route. Thanks for the answer - gonna go try it now and let you know...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joseph :) but I wasn't able to scroll the content in the div independent of the whole window with this solution.